# If a word can be both an adjective and a verb, can you still use the past principle as an adjective?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, adjectives, past-participles

For example, the word "averse" could serve as both a verb and an adjective. Can I still use "aversed" as an adjective? Are "more aversed" and "more averse" the same thing?

For another example, are "more cleaned" and "cleaner" both good grammar and meaning the same thing?

Comment: I'd like to know what dictionary lists 'averse' as a verb. The usual usage is of the form 'He is averse [more averse / less averse] to the wearing of socks with sandals'.  // With the more reasonable second example, 'The room is cleaner' or 'The room has been more thoroughly cleaned' work. 'This room is more thoroughly cleaned' or more idiomatically 'This room is cleaned more thoroughly' are possible, but would default to the 'gets a better cleaning [each week]' sense.

Comment: @edwin-ashworth The OED does list *averse* as a verb, too, with the meaning of  'to turn away'. However, it marks such usage as obsolete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are talking about adjective/verb pairs such that the adjective form is the same as the base form of the verb. Examples include *clean* (*I cleaned the house*/*the house is clean*), *faint* (*He is about to faint*/*That sound is too faint to hear*), *prompt* (*I have to prompt you to do that*/*He is always prompt*), and others. Let's call such words **‘adjectiverbs’** (following [Archive.org: Oxford Dictionaries blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20160110095931/http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2013/11/whats-wrong-with-this-verb/)).

Whether you can use the past participle of **any** verb (adjectiverb or not) as an adjective will vary from case to case. If you can, then whether such an adjective is gradeable (i.e. allows modification by *more* and *the most*) will also vary from case to case. Furthermore, in the particular case of adjectiverbs, if the past participle can function as an adjective, it will not generally be interchangeable with the base form adjective.

In short:

1. For verbs in general (regardless of whether or not they are adjectiverbs), the past participle form of the verb may or may not be usable as an adjective. For example, *worried* (the past participle of *to worry*) is usable as an adjective, but *heard* (the past participle of *to hear*) is not; see below.
2. For adjectiverbs, if the past participle form of the verb **is** usable as an adjective (e.g. *cleaned*), it is generally not interchangeable with the adjective that looks like the verb in its base form (*clean*). For example, it wouldn't make sense to replace *clean* by *cleaned* in the following sentence: *Some things are clean because they were never dirty in the first place.* The reason is that *cleaned* suggests that some cleansing action had taken place, whereas *clean* doesn't necessarily.
3. As far as gradeability (*clean/cleaner/cleanest*), note that, in general, not all adjectives are gradeable. In the case of adjectiverbs, it is not clear if gradeability of one kind of adjective (say, the one that looks like the base form of the verb, e.g. *clean*) implies anything about the gradeability of the other kind (the one that looks like the past participle form of the verb, e.g. *cleaned*). For example, if *fainted* is an adjective (although it might not be; see below), it is not gradeable, whereas the adjective *faint* certainly is (*a fainter sound*).
4. Note that the verb *to averse* is listed in the Oxford English Dictionary (OED) as 'obsolete'; for what it's worth, its meaning is *to turn away*. Here are some better examples of adjectiverbs (from [this list](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2013/11/14/whats-wrong-with-this-verb/)). For all of them, the verb etymologically derives from the adjective (see the preceding link).

> prompt                   second            slow                   mellow              moderate   
> ready                           clear               smooth        quiet                     blunt
> dull                              round         shy                           complete          clean
> approximate        narrow        dizzy                      faint                          fit

**Preliminary remarks: verbs vs adjectives**

One general note on verbs and adjectives: for some verbs, the past-participle (and/or present-participle) form of the verb can function as an adjective, while for other verbs it cannot and has the passive meaning. The ultimate test that enables one to decide whether such a participle-like form can or cannot function as an adjective is whether it can function as a predicative complement (PC).

For example, consider the following pair of expressions ([CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468), p. 541):

[1] a. *a rarely **heard** work by Purcell*
      b. *her very **worried** parents*

To test whether the boldfaced words are adjectives or verbs, we try to make them work as PCs of some verb *other* than ***be***, such as *seem*, *become*, or *appear*. (This test would be inconclusive with ***be*** because in that case the resulting expression could be acceptable simply because it may be interpretable as a passive voice construction.)

[2] a. **the work by Purcell seems **heard***
      b. *her parents seem **worried***

[2a] is unacceptable, and so *heard* cannot be interpreted as an adjective. In contrast, [2b] is acceptable, and so *worried* **is** an adjective. Further evidence that *worried* is an adjective is that it allows modification by *very*, as in [1b]. (On the other hand, **a very heard work by Purcell* is not acceptable.)

*Worried* is even **gradeable**: *her parents seemed **more worried** than usual*. However, not all adjectives are gradeable, so lack of gradeability is not good evidence that something is *not* an adjective.

**Three specific examples of 'adjectiverbs'**

***Prompt***

As a verb, *to prompt* has several related meanings. One is to *cause or bring about (an action or feeling)*; another, to *prompt someone to/to do something* is to cause someone to take a course of action; yet another, to *encourage (a hesitating speaker) to say something*, or *supply a forgotten word or line to (an actor) during the performance of a play*; and finally, there is a meaning connected to a computer *requesting input from (a user)*. (See [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prompt).)

As an adjective, however, its meaning is very different: *done without delay; immediate*. This even though etymologically, the verb *prompt* is ('apparently', according to the OED) derived from the adjective *prompt*.

Now we consider *prompted*. The first question is whether this can function as an adjective at all. Well, a search of google books for e.g. "seem prompted to" returns numerous hits, such as

[3] *I **seemed prompted** to investigate further.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=wihKDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA20&dq=%22seemed%20prompted%20to%22&pg=PA20#v=onepage&q=%22seemed%20prompted%20to%22&f=false)

Thus, *prompted* can indeed function as an adjective (and it is even listed as such in the OED).

But the adjectives *prompted* and *prompt* are not at all equivalent: their meanings are different. If I am *prompt*, that means I do things without delay; but if I am *prompted*, it means that someone or something caused me to act.

***Clean***

The OED does list *cleaned* as an adjective, with the meaning *freed from dirt, cleansed*. In google books, we do find attested examples such as

[4] *And when her house was clean and quiet and the air **seemed cleaned** again, ... her fondness for the family came back.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=norGRtOjSx4C&lpg=PA386&dq=%22seemed%20cleaned%22&pg=PA386#v=onepage&q=%22seemed%20cleaned%22&f=false)

The adjectives *clean* and *cleaned* are much closer in meaning than *prompt* and *prompted*, but are arguably not completely equivalent. *Cleaned* suggests that some cleansing action had occured, whereas *clean* does not necessarily. In particular, one could not use *cleaned* in such sentences as

[5]  *Nothing about coal is clean.*

***Faint***

The adjective *faint* has the following cluster of meanings: *barely perceptible*; (of a hope or chance) *possible but unlikely*; *lacking conviction or enthusiasm*; (in predicative function only) *feeling weak and dizzy and close to losing consciousness*.

The verb means *to lose consciousness for a short time because of a temporarily insufficient supply of oxygen to the brain* (there is also an archaic meaning of *grow weak or feeble; decline*).

In this case, however, *fainted* used as an adjective (e.g. *seemed/became fainted*) is of marginal acceptability. There are some hits for it on google books—predominantly by authors from India, although there are some by others—but it is not listed as an adjective in the OED. In all cases when it **is** used as an adjective, however, it would seem to refer to the state of being unconscious. So it would not be interchangeable with the adjective *faint* in e.g. its meaning of *barely perceptible*. For example, you can say *a faint sound*, but not **a fainted sound*.

Comment: @Lawrence You are right; thanks for pointing it out! I removed that from the answer (I don't have a ready example that does work.)

Comment: You're welcome. If you point out that *prompted* and *prompt* have completely different meanings in that example, it still serves to illustrate your point that the similar-looking forms are not interchangeable. I think having the illustration makes your point more clearly.

Comment: @Lawrence In 2. at the beginning of the answer, I added an example with *clean/cleaned*. It is purely semantic. But I still think it would be nice to have a syntactic example, however, e.g. one where the two kinds of adjectives license different complements.

Comment: @linguisticturn A clear and comprehensive answer, but I'm still uncertain about one aspect. Are you saying that in the phrase "a rarely heard work by Purcell," heard is a verb because the test sentence "the work by Purcell seems heard" is unacceptable? But what if  the adverb were included: "(Anecdotally) the work by Purcell seems rarely heard." Is that unacceptable?  If not, what part of speech is "heard" in that sentence?

Comment: @Zan700 It does sound dubious to me... and *appears rarely heard* even more so.